# Powershell Script Timeout After 130 Seconds

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that runs a console .exe application.  The console application runs a web service.  The webservice takes approx 10 mins to complete a task.

In a production environment the powershell script finishes after approx 130 seconds and the web service task is terminated.  This is the core problem!  Everything works just fine in a local environment.

Powershell version 2 is running both locally and in production.

When running the powershell script from the console.  Locally, the powershell script prints the return value of the console app.  In production, nothing is printed to the screen.  It just displays a new command prompt.

The task can be run async from a web page in the production environment just fine.

All application code/config files are the same on both local/production environments.

The only thing that makes sense is the powershell script is timing out and terminating the console app that in turn terminates the web service.

Have researched powershell timeouts and have played with different scripts.  But the fact that it works locally seems to indicate a powershell default setting problem.

This page describes timeout settings:
http://www.ehow.com/how_12026004_set-timeout-powershell.html

But running: Dir WSMan:\localhost\shell results in a path not found error when run in production.

Powerscript is below but has had all sensitive information removed.  Success email is sent after script is run.

```
# attempt to exe file.  iex is an alias for the invoke-expression cmd
iex "Reminder.exe"

$smtpServer = ""
$fromAddress = ""
$toAddress = ""
$subject = "SUCCESS"
$msgBody = ""

# $? lets us know if the previous command was successful or not
# $LASTEXITCODE gives us the exit code of the last Win32 exe execution
if (!$? -OR $LASTEXITCODE -gt 0)
{
$subject = "FAIL"
}

$smtpClient = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtpClient.Credentials = $senderCreds
$smtpClient.Send($fromAddress,$toAddress,$subject,$msgBody)
```

Comment: One thing of note is you should use `&` to invoke Win32 programs instead of `Invoke-Expression` such as `& reminder.exe`. See more info from the Windows PowerShell blog about `Invoke-Expression` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: Just to clarify, `reminder.exe` is your console application that runs the web service, correct? Also you could you describe in a little more detail the difference between the production environment and your local environment in terms of how you are invoking the script? Are you using PowerShell remoting to run the script remotely on the production system?

Comment: Correct - reminder.exe is the console app that runs the web server.  There are no differences that I'm aware of between local and production.  Local is actually a Windows Server 2008 R2 box being used for local development.  The production server is the same.  The powershell script is simply being run from the powershell command line (for testing purposes).

Tried the $ but can't get the syntax right. reminder.exe actually has a full path with spaces.  Are you able to provide a quick example?

Comment: Try running this command on your production box to see if you have the same problem. This will simulate a long running Win32 application: `& ping.exe localhost -n 300 >$NULL`. This run ping.exe for about 300 seconds. You can also measure the time it takes using `Measure-Command {& ping.exe localhost -n 300}`.

Comment: Ping ran just fine.  I stopped it after 4 minutes.  Also checked both servers are 64bit and console app set to run any CPU (x86, x64). Would like to try running reminder.exe with $ but still can't find a syntax that works.  e.g. $ D:/wwwroot/Reminder/bin/Release/Reminder.exe results in The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @user464435 - He said `&` and not `$`, why are you trying `$`??

Comment: @user464435 Make sure to use the ampersand (`&`) instead the dollar sign when invoking Win32 executables. If the command `& ping.exe localhost -n 300 >$NULL` ran on your production machine and returned to a prompt as expected it would suggest there isn't a timeout issue.

Comment: oh right an & - that works!  Changed iex to & in the script and got the same result.  So now I'm totally stumped.  Again the powershell script ended without printing the results of the console app.  Will go searching logs again for clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an incorrect assumption here.  The powershell script was not returning the results of the console application.  The console application was failing.  But because the script output a "0" I assumed it was successful (as returned by the console application).  Adding the following line to the powershell script returned the actual return value:

```
Write-Host "CONSOLEEXITCODE : $LASTEXITCODE"
```

Now that it was clear the console application was failing and not the powershell script (as proven by the clever ping test suggested) I added a Console.WriteLine to write the error (to the powershell command window):

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match th
>   e content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSuppor
>   ted method is implemented properly.

This led me on a wild goose chase.  It was until I trapped and logged all web service and task errors that I found the following error in the task:

> Thread was being aborted.

The fix was as simple as increasing the "thread" timeout:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 900; // in seconds
```

A better solution may be to run this asynchronously in a separate thread.

This a list of timeouts required for this process to work. Code will of course vary depending on language/implementation:

```
C# Task: HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 
C# Web Service (that calls task): this.Session.Timeout = 
C# Console Application (that calls web service): mySoapClient.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = 
Powershell script (that calls console application): not required
```